# Sharepoint online list in an MVC application

Tags: sharepoint-online, asp.net, mvc

I'm trying to build an MVC ASP.NET appthat read in my sharepoint online a list I included in MVC the Azure Active directory login, but I don't understand how to pass the credential to sharepoint site. I use the Stefano's tutorial to build my app Thank you …

Answer (score 1):

here is the function that will return authenticated **ClientContext** object:

**Sample Code:**

```
public ClientContext Auth(String uname, String pwd,string siteURL) {
ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteURL);
Web web = context.Web;
SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in pwd.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, passWord);
try
{
    context.Load(web);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine("Olla! from " + web.Title + " site");
    return context;
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong in Auth Module" + e);
    Console.ReadKey();
    return null; 
}
}
```

**Ref** : https://coderwall.com/p/ho2uwq/authentication-in-sharepoint-2013-using-c-csom-client

**Required dll**: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM

**Note:** best approach to store your username and password would be **web.config** file of you MVC project.